# Что такое Task List

Tags: eclipse

Что такое Task List в Eclipse Indigo и для чего он существует

Answer (score 2):

Он существует, как ни странно, для ведения списка задач. Можно использовать коннекторы к разным баг-трэкерам.

Comment: Это туда записываешь задачи, которые нужно выполнить?

Comment: ну вроде того, так же если подключен какой-нибудь багтрэкер отображаются задачи из него